# Traverse JSON object to create jsTree

Tags: javascript, json, jstree, traversal, tree-traversal

I want to create a jsTree from JSON with different depth (could be 10 or more levels). So I searched the web and found a method to create the jsTree: traversing.

**Example JSON:**

```
{
    "testslave_1": {
        "DevKey": "94ssfsafafeaw382",
        "mapping": {
            "device1": "D1",
            "device2": "D2",
            "device3": "D3"
        }
    }
}
```

Lucky for me there is [traverse-js](https://github.com/substack/js-traverse) but I have problems with it.

**This is the syntax required by jsTree:**

```
$('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
    ]
} });
```

I have tried this so far:

```
var obj = '{    "testslave_1": {        "DevKey": "94ssfsafafeaw382",       "mapping": {            "device1": "D1",            "device2": "D2",            "device3": "D3"     }   }}';

    var obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    var arr = [];

    traverse(obj).map(function (x) {
        
    var jsonTemp = '{ "id" : "'+this.path+'", "parent" : "'+this.parent+'", "text" : "'+this.node+'" }';
    jsonTemp = JSON.parse(jsonTemp);
    arr.push(jsonTemp);
        
    });

    console.dir(arr);
```

But there are serveral problems: How to create an specific ID for each item? (the function may remember the id for the parent-attribute)

It says object object, if I understand it in the right way I have to access the node of the parent object. But how? this.parent.node does not work.

There are items missing, it should be around 10 items.

Is my way of the solution going in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea of traverse-js. If you want to get some kind of tree structure like the example you can achieve that with a recursive function, for example like this one:

```
var testobj = {
    testslave_1:{
        DevKey: "94ssfsafafeaw382",
        mapping: {
            device1:"D1",
            device2:"D2",
            device3:"D3"
        }
    }
};
var tree = {
    core: {
        data: []
    }
};
function createTreeData(object, parent){
    if(!parent){
        parent = "#"
    }
    for(var prop in object){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            var obj = {
                id: prop,
                parent: parent
            };
            if(typeof object[prop] === "object"){
                createTreeData(object[prop], prop);
                obj.text = "parent node";
            }else{
                obj.text = object[prop];
            }
            tree.core.data.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
createTreeData(testobj);
console.log(tree);
```

The only thing which this function doesn't provide is text for the elements which are parentNodes themselves. Instead it puts in the child objects which is most likely wrong. But you didn't specify what text parent nodes should contain.

**EDIT:** I changed the function so that parent nodes now contain the text "parent node" rather than their child object.

**EDIT2:** New function which makes nodes for properties which are just text:

```
function createTreeData(object, parent){
    if(!parent){
        parent = "#"
    }
    for(var prop in object){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            tree.core.data.push({
                id: prop,
                parent: parent,
                text: prop
            });
            if(typeof object[prop] === "object"){
                createTreeData(object[prop], prop);
            }else{
                tree.core.data.push({
                    id: object[prop],
                    parent: prop,
                    text: object[prop]
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First: Thank you! You are right, I have not specified what information the parent should contain. It should have the name of the parent itself. In this case, "DevKey" is not present in the tree. It would be perfect if the structure would be "testslave_1"->"DevKey"->94ssfsafafeaw382, just like the json structure. I have changed obj.text = "parent node"; to obj.text = prop; so that the other parent elements are named right. How to create a parent item for  ""94ssfsafafeaw382"? 
It should look like this:
http://imgur.com/a/2JKBc

At the moment it looks like this:
http://imgur.com/a/OiwOH

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. If the current one is incorrect, then the mappings are incorrect as well, because device1, device2 and device3 do not show up in the tree. Then you have to modify the function so that it makes sub-nodes for properties which only contain a value, too. If mappings and devices are correct, you have to adjust the input JSON to something like ... "DevKey": { "text": "94ssfsafafeaw382"}, ...

Comment: You are right, I have forgotten to add the Device1 and so on.
This is how it should look like: http://imgur.com/a/C33Qn
Every element should be visible in the tree.
As far as I understand it the function has to be modified that it runs another time for the sub-node, right?

Comment: I would not make it run another time for the sub-node, but make it create a second tree element if the property is not an object but text. I edited in a second version of the function.